# G-rated word lists in various languages for programming children's games

Tags: game-design

I'm programming a word guessing game that uses large lists of words (no definitions, just words). Word length is configurable. Parents could set the word length to be very short and let small children play the game. I'd like to make sure there are no obviously obscene words in the list. For American English, the closest I've found was a Scrabble-like dictionary file that uniformly labelled questionable words with "obscene" so I can easily filter them out. Does anyone know of a better list in English, and/or any lists in other languages?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a game-specific topic.

Comment: Related possible duplicate (just different use cases): http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15109/profanity-filter-for-an-mmo-chat Additionally, this is kind of a "which technology to use" and not solely within game development.

Comment: There is one small problem with your approach that Disney found out the hard way: [*"I want to stick my long-necked giraffe up your fluffy white bunny."*](http://habitatchronicles.com/2007/03/the-untold-history-of-toontowns-speedchat-or-blockchattm-from-disney-finally-arrives/)

Comment: I think this perfectly on-topic.  That it could also be asked on SO or some other SE site does not preclude it being game related and this site being a good audience to answer it.

Comment: I re-read the thread posted above, and noticed "google for profanity". Googling for lists without profanity didn't work well but specifically googling for profanity in various languages looks very promising. Wikipedia even has entries for profanities in other languages. Thanks to all for helping me re-frame the question.

Comment: This is only tangentially related to game development: The main issue is language. It may belong on the *English Language & Usage* SE.