# List of 3 letter English words to disallow from entry for public kids game

Tags: leaderboards, community-management

I saw [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15109/profanity-filter-for-an-mmo-chat) about a profanity filter for an mmo chat.

In my case I've got a game played in public, mostly by kids. The only text they can enter is their initials A-Z, 2 or 3 letters.

With only 2 letters I think I'm safe. But, I'd prefer 3. Alas, 3 letter nicknames would allow for such names as `ASS`, `FUK`, `COK`, `DIK` and `SHT`, `CNT` etc. although the last few are more open to interpretation than the first. I'd just like not to get negative feedback from parents or other adults. I saw the lists linked to above didn't include `FUK` so I'm wondering whether anyone knows of a list that only includes 3 letter words, maybe left over from arcade machines or something.

Note: I've displayed the game in public before with adults with a 20 letter limit and without fail 1 or 2 people will put `8======D~` or some short rude sentence. While I don't care with adults, the next event will be 5-15yr old kids, their parents, and also adults without kids. So if there is a list of 3 letter words to avoid I'd allow 3 letters. If I can't find such a list I'll probably just go with 2 and avoid the problem.

Anyone know of such a list?

Comment: allow reporting and removing such entries

Comment: What is the question exactly? Usage/Implementation/Link ?

Comment: relevant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: The *Scunthorpe* problem is unrelated. That problem requires real words and or sentences. I'm limited the problem to 3 letters, no sentences. There are so few words you can make that it should be relatively easy to have such a list. There are only 17576 combinations of 3 A-Z letters. Of those very few suggest something that a parent would complain about.

as for ratchet freaks suggestion, imagine this is a game at Disneyland on a large display that hundreds of kids and their parents can see at once. I think they'd prefer not to see `FUK` up there rather than deal with it after it's too late.

Comment: If you go with only two letters you probably still want to ban FU and perhaps BO, perhaps a few others I can't recall to mind.

Comment: Scunthorpe completley related. this is philosophical, you take it too much on the practical side. what you try to do is censorship.

Comment: "Related" is a relative term. It's a similar problem but not the same. Like, no there's not much room to have a naughty word in the middle of 3 innocent letters, but it does have the same problem of someone's real initials could honestly be ASS or COK or whatever. You can't just censor out initials blindly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in addition to vulgarity other words may be inappropriate, for example "KKK" or "LSD".

It may also pay to consider any local sensitivities for demographics you are targeting, for example if releasing a "gun game" in the United Kingdom or Ireland I would consider "IRA", for Chicago would consider "CPD"

---

Kenneth Hurley has a *very* comprehensive list of [bad words](https://github.com/klhurley/ElementalEngine2/blob/master/Common/Databases/BadWords.dbx) included in the ElementalEngine2 repository on GitHub.

The author has [indicated](https://github.com/klhurley/ElementalEngine2/issues/1) these can be used freely.

---

Another good source of candidates for consideration is the blacklists used by vehicle licensing agencies when issuing license plates. The lists as provided by the DMVs of a number of US States have been collected by Government Attic and published [here](http://www.governmentattic.org/StateDMV-ForbidPlates.html) (California is a good example).

Answer (score 17):

If the kids are supposed to enter their initials, I don’t think you should block any combination. On LinkedIn, [there are 25 professionals named Carol O’Keefe](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/Carol/O'Keefe/+/). How about [Andrew S. Schwartz](http://records.ancestry.ca/andrew_s_schwartz_records.ashx?pid=66984361)?

If you want kids to be able to choose an online identity without allowing profanity, you could consider a pre-determined combination of icons, animal pictures, colours, etc. instead.

Answer (score 1):

The bad words and Elemental Engine2 is completely open source BSD/Mit like licensing.  You can do with it what you want to, commercial, private, etc.

If you don't like the original license for some reason, just let me know